# diff ignore comment

Tags: bash, diff

I'm trying to compare 2 different apaches config directories.
But I want to avoid the difference between versions. For example I'm going to compare between 2.2.20 and 2.2.21.

This what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/ksh

source=/root/daniel/scripts/test
dest=/root/daniel/scripts/test2

# TODO: rewrite as awk script
delta=`diff -ur $source $dest`

deleted=`echo "$delta" | grep "^Only in ${source}:" | sed "/^Only in ${source}: //"`
added=`echo "$delta"   | grep "^Only in ${dest}:"   | sed "/^Only in ${dest}: //"`
changed=`echo "$delta" | grep '^\+\+\+' | awk '{print $2}'`

print "Files deleted in destination"
echo $deleted
print "Files Added in destination"
echo $added
print "Files Changed in destination"
echo $changed
```

Adding a comment.
Basically, I'm going to compare the 2 config directories. You can find the apache version in httpd.conf file. But the idea is to ignore the version in all the comparison.

Adding a comment 2.
The test and test2 are directories, they are not files. In the 2 directories you can find all the config files for apache.
More or less this:
 + extra
 + httpd.conf
 + httpd.conf_20110215
 + magic
 + mime.types
 + original
 + ssl.crt
 + ssl.key
 + temp

Thanks

Comment: Where is the version in the files?

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `test` and `test2` files?

Comment: a duplicate question. see the answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/how-to-diff-files-ignoring-comments-lines-starting-with

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-I` option in diff to ignore the lines.

From `man diff`

> -I RE  --ignore-matching-lines=RE
>
> ```
>       Ignore changes whose lines all match RE.
> ```